# Flex 4 converting array.length into a string

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, data-binding, flex4

so I am trying to assign a number to a variable that is dynically generated from a binded array...when i try and assign it and trace it out nothing happens, which means I am obviously doing something wrong but I am not sure? just for fun i decided to bind the data to a label like so...

```
<s:Label text="{this.dd.selectedViews.length}"/>
```

and that work and updated properly, but when running in debug mode i got this warning...

```
warning: unable to bind to property 'length' on class 'Array' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)
```

so what would be the best method of assigning the array to a variable to use throughout my application

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: have you tried `this.dd.selectedViews.length.toString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking here, but maybe this will help you out.  As your error message says, the `Array` class is not an IEventDispatcher.  What that means is that if you try to use a plain old `Array` as the source of a data-binding expression, it generally is not going to work.

If you need to bind to an array, you can try using a different class such as [ArrayCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html), which supports data binding.

Comment: Beat me to it. Wesley is correct; if you want to bind to the array's length you'll need to wrap it in an ArrayCollection. Or, manage the label's text property manually by updating it whenever you call a function on the array that modifies its length.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, this is the ea1xact answer i was looking for, thank you